# Просто скажите как это понять? Не понимаю что должен делать этот плагин

Tags: javascript, html

Реализовать свой собственный плагин для работы с xhr. Должна быть возможность указания заголовков, адреса, коллбэк ответа сервера. Скрипт должен загружаться на страницу отдельно и использоваться как плагин. Использовать $.ajax запрещается

Comment: [https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest) и [https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch](https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch); Есть жизнь и без JQ)

Comment: посмотрите на `$.ajax` и реализуйте свой

Comment: Этот плагин должен быть обёрткой над стандартным `XMLHttpRequest`. Эдакая альтернатива обёртке из jQuery (`$.ajax`) и куче других, а также удовлетворяющая указанным условиям

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы, теперь понял что мне надо изучить и куда двигаться!